# Do Efimov states contribute to fusion reactions other than the triple-alpha process?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, stars, fusion

An [Efimov state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efimov_state) is a three-body quantum state in which each two-body subsystem is unbound, but the system as a whole is bound because of the large s-wave scattering length.  Intuitively, one can imagine that a three-body force binds the system via the ‘shuttling’ back and forth of one of the particles. [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.08432.pdf)

Due to the existence of a (theoretically) infinite series of excited Efimov states near resonance, the effect has a long-range nature.  Under certain conditions, it can have an outsized impact on nuclear interactions.  For example, below about 0.15 GK (13 keV), the Efimov state contribution to the rate of the triple-alpha process [dominates](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.08432.pdf) the contribution from the better-known Hoyle state.  Although the Hoyle state is far more important at higher temperatures and is responsible for most of the carbon created in stars, the Efimov state determines the ignition temperature and alters the final C/O and C/Ne ratios.

Could the same process be significant in other stellar fusion reactions as well?  For example, is it plausible that an Efimov-like effect could allow three-body deuterium fusion at an enhanced rate – perhaps in very dense, cold objects?